# Can I disable canvas size limit in inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

Inkscape is incredibly annoying with it's size limit that looks so awfully in browsers. Is there any way to have a canvas with no limits and simply adjust scroll bars to the existing objects, much like browsers do?

*What do I mean by the canvas limit:*
In inkscape, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>. You'll see a popup offering the the canvas size.
In the default settings, the canvas size is the size of a A4 sheet of paper. If you exceed it, the content you've created will be hidden (in browser).

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more as to what annoys you? So far, I can only guess.

Comment: I tried to further explain. I wrote the original post with a little bit of fury, which was no good.

Answer (score 0):

I am still not entirely sure whether I correctly understood your problem, but *Resize Page to contents* might be what you are after.

For example, you have two rectangles exceeding the current page boundary:

[image: Before Resizing]

And after *Resize page to drawing or selection* (with no additional margins):

[image: After Resizing]

Comment: This is what I did, but I'm forced to do this manually whenever the layout changes.